# LIF spectrum with laser-coupled levels lines as the strongest

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy

Why, if I excited the OH molecule Q-branch transition, my LIF spectrum (recorded during and after the laser pulse) does not result in only Q line being the most prominent, but also P and R lines with $\Delta J = \pm 1?$

How/why are these coupled?

Comment: You give little experimental detail  so is it possible that (a) collisions in the excited state (which can have a lifetime of  several hundred ns) cause population of other levels and (b) your laser bandwidth is wider than  you anticipate and so several rotational levels are populated.